# How to build 32bit program for 64bit Linux using Visual C++ for Linux Development in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

the remote machine I connect is 64bit, when I use Visual C++ for Linux Development to build 32bit program for my remote machine, I got this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.Common.targets(51,5): error : Current project architecture 'x86' is incompatible with the remote system architecture 'x64' ('x64'). Please switch the project architecture to 'x64' in Configuration Manager.

however, when I use g++ with -m32, it was done.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ for Linux Development 1.0.5 (and earlier) is very particular about matching remote architecture and the project target. There is an issue open for this on the [VCLinux GitHub site](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux) .

Comment: The exact issue is https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/25 , which is nowadays closed with a suggestion to report to Dev Comminity Forum.